# ios: Google Drive REST API v3: Internal error 500

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am using Google Drive Rest API on ios 10.1 and am able to list file metadata and obtain file content.

I get Internal Error 500 when I try to create a file in the appDataFolder. I would appreciate your insights on this.

Here is my code:

```
     NSURL *url = [[ NSURL alloc ] initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO ];

     GTLRUploadParameters *uploadParameters = [ GTLRUploadParameters uploadParametersWithFileURL:url
                                                                                        MIMEType:mimeType];
     GTLRDriveQuery *query ;

     if (metadata == NULL)
     {
         metadata = [ GTLRDrive_File object ];

         metadata.name = fileName;

         if (folderId != NULL)
         {
             metadata.parents = @[ folderId ];
         }

         // This is a new file, instantiate an insert query.
         query =  [ GTLRDriveQuery_FilesCreate queryWithObject:metadata
                                              uploadParameters:uploadParameters ];
     }
     else
     {
         // This file already exists, instantiate an update query.
         query = [ GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate queryWithObject:metadata
                                                       fileId:metadata.identifier
                                             uploadParameters:uploadParameters ];
     }

     query.fields = queryFileFieldsParam;

     [ weakSelf.googleDriveService executeQuery:query completionHandler:^(GTLRServiceTicket *ticket,
                                                                          GTLRDrive_File *updatedMetadata,
                                                                          NSError *error)
      {
          if (error == nil)
          {
              completionBlock(updatedMetadata);
          }
          else
          {
              NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);

          }
      }];
```

Comment: what is ur mime-type, could u show it

Comment: The file is in a custom binary format, so the mime-type has this format:"application/prs.<company name>-apps.<extension>"

Comment: A 500 error is a bug on the server. You should report it to the Google Drive team. Maybe try the Google Plus community here: https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037

Comment: Thanks, I will try that